# AppActivate doesn't work with process id

Tags: vb.net, vba

```
Declare Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "user32.dll" () As Int32

Declare Function GetWindowThreadProcessId Lib "user32.dll" (
    ByVal hwnd As Int32,
    ByRef lpdwProcessId As Int32) As Int32

Public Function RetCurTitle() As Integer
    Dim processID As Int32
    Return GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetForegroundWindow(), processID)
End Function
```

I use the above function to get the process id of the active window. It returns 4060.

After that I call

```
AppActivate(4060)
```

And the app crashes. I tried using integer variable in place of the 4060 but same problem.

Comment: You are not using GetWindowThreadProcessId() correctly.  You are returning the *thread ID* of the thread that owns the window, not the process ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `RetCurTitle()` function is returning the return value of `GetWindowThreadProcessId()`, which is the thread ID, not the process ID. Change your function to:

```
Public Function RetCurTitle() As Int32
    Dim processID As Int32
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetForegroundWindow(), processID)
    Return processID
End Function
```